# How do I fix "Assertion Failed" - FireQuickVerifySSL

Tags: c#, ssl, visual-studio-2013

I have recently been getting the below error whenever I try to publish code to our MS Server using VS2013.

[image]

It didn't used to do this, and its really irritating when it interrupts publishing and jumps in front when I'm multitasking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting my computer seemed to fix this problem, I assume it was caused by our SSL certs on our server weren't agreeing with what was saved locally.